# Alamofire: How to retry request only once

Tags: count, request, alamofire, retrypolicy

I'm adopting `RequestAdapter` and `RequestRetrier` to add refresh token behavior  automatically to my request.
The problems that retry occurs indefinitely without control.
I have this code:

```
class AuthHandler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {

        return urlRequest

    }

    public func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {

        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {

            _ = Credential.current.renew({ (credential, error) in
                completion(true, 0.0) /// Retry request
            })

        } else {

            completion(false, 0.0) // Don't retry

        }

    }

}
```

How can I do the request retry only once after fails?

I tried this:

```
request.retryCount = 1
```

but doesn't works... Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`retryCount` is read-only. The description for `retryCount` is:

> The number of times the request has been retried.

So, all you need to do is check this retry count, and stop the retry if the `retryCount` is too high.

To stop after one retry, this code would work:

```swift
class AuthHandler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        return urlRequest
    }

    public func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {

        guard request.retryCount == 0 else { return completion(false, 0) } // relevant change

        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {

            _ = Credential.current.renew({ (credential, error) in
                completion(true, 0) /// Retry request
            })

        } else {
            completion(false, 0.0) // Don't retry
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** the first time a request is retried, its `retryCount` is 0. In our code above, we are making sure it's only on its very first retry, where the `retryCount == 0`.

Comment: does anyone know why retry() (alamofire 5) / should() (alamofire 4) is called twice when 401 ? why is it called twice ?

Comment: @omarojo, because default request retry count = 2, and when you get error for first time will send second request. Probably yours interceptor has a mistake. Probably you need set newToken in the second request in adapter.